# Partial Fraction Expansion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, partial-fractions

I am to use MATLAB to find the partial fraction expansion of the following function. Can this be done in that format or do I have to manipulate the function?

Note: This must be done using pure MATLAB only. No add-ons or anything like that. Not even Math Toolbox.

[image: Expand this]

Comment: Short of writing some code to solve for the coefficients of the partial fraction expansion (essentially collecting terms to construct a system of linear equations, then using Matlab to solve the system), I'm not sure there is a "pure Matlab only" approach.

Answer (score 5):

The matlab function residue does the job. For multiplication of the polynomial roots to convert to standard form use conv:

```
b = 1e4*conv( [1 5], [1 70] );
a = conv( [1 0], conv([1 45], conv([1 55], conv([1 7 110],[1 6 95]) ) ) );

[r, p, k] = residue(b,a);
```

with r, p and k containing the partial fraction decomposition:

$\frac{b(s)}{a(s)} = k + \sum_i \frac{r_i}{s - p_i}$

check also documentation of the residue function. It is part of the base package and does not need toolboxes.

Comment: I know for sure residue function is for s-domain however if we use it in z-domain it gives our mathematically matched answer but not with z-domain function residuez. Any taker please?

Comment: @Khaaba: `residuez` computes the partial fraction expansion with respect to variable $z^{-1}$, which is the convention needed in discrete time systems theory. The `residue` function calculates the partial fraction decomposition in the mathematical sense. It is a matter of convention and `residuez` can be simulated in terms of `residue` with some adaption of the input polynomial.

Comment: I got it. I tried myself today morning and what you are saying true. I took time for me understand. Thank you.